# ffmpeg overlay picture not every frame

Tags: android, ffmpeg

To overlay picture on video I use next command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pic.png -strict -2 -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' result.mp4
```

But as I can see it takes quite a lot of time to process even small HD video. I want overlay image on my android device, so I need some performance hacks.

Are there any commands to overlay image on each 10's frame, which is suitable for human eye?

Comment: Can you clarify: how often and how long each time?

Comment: For example I have 2 min video at 720p. To overlay even small png pic takes a lot of time (about 3 min), which is extremely lot for mobile device. For example my video has 10k frames. I need to overlay each frame. But if I will skip about 10 frames, I will make this process 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple image overlay using the following syntax:

```
   ffmpeg -y 
  -i foo.mp4 -i foo.jpg -i
  -filter_complex "
      [0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0.1,0.11)' [tmp];
      [tmp][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,1.1,1.11)' [tmp];
      ....
  " 
bar.mp4
```

`overlay=25:25` means we want to position the image 25px to the left and 25px down, originating from the top left corner.

`enable='between(t,0.1,0.11)'` means we want the image to show between second 0.1 and 0.11 .

Comment: I see, I also found this answer on stackoverflow :) But I need command to skip frames.

Comment: How can I put this values into variables? To loop this to show image every 0.5 seconds for example